# Adding CSS styles to injected DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am using javascript to inject a few DOM elements into the page. I am able to inject a single DOM element and apply CSS style to it:

```
var $e = $('<div id="header"></div>');
$('body').append($e);

$e.css({
    background: '#fbf7f7',
});
```

**Problem:** If I have nested elements within `$e`, how can I apply CSS styles to the parents and its children seperately?

```
var $e = $('<div id="header"><div class="header-content"><span class="title"></span></div></div>');
```

Comment: Can't you access elements using their id or class? For example $("#header") or $("#header .header-content")

Comment: Right, I was thinking using `$e` instead of selecting through their classes and ids will prevent variable name clashes if the classes and ids already exist on the page its injecting into. If i select by id and classname, there may be clashes

Comment: Well, if ids already exist that would be a major concern, not just for css. It makes sense for class names. If it's really children you need, then just go with $e.children().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have applied class to `div` inside parent element you can simply create a style to that `class header-content` and apply it.

In order to apply styles dynamically you can simply add class for individual elements like this

```
$('#id-of-element').addClass("header-content");
```

you can also find elements inside parent element like the one below

```
$e.find('.header-content').css('background-color', '#ccc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add css to any element using .css() method... Try the following example. I have added a div inside $e and applied different style... the thing is to use the id or class of the child inside parent div...

```
var $e = $('<div id="header"><div id="child"></div></div>');
$('body').append($e);

$e.css({
    background: '#fbf7f7',
});
$('#child').css("background", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comments: if you need to access children regardless of any id or class, then just use `$e.children()`.